# How can I share match patterns between keys?

Tags: xslt, key, xslt-2.0

I have two keys with the same match pattern. The pattern is long. The pattern itself doesn't matter; the problem is the long duplication:

```
  <xsl:key name="narrow-things-by-columnset" match="p | p-cont |
    heading[not(parent::section or parent::contents) and not(parent::p)] |
    language-desc | country-desc | graphic[not(parent::section or parent::contents)] |
    block-quote | bulleted-list | blank-line |
    bibliography | language-name-index | language-code-index | country-index | table-of-contents" 
    use="sileth:columnset-id(.)"/>

  <!-- TODO: DRY: I would love to be able to share the above match pattern instead of
    duplicating it. -->
  <xsl:key name="narrow-things-by-section" match="p | p-cont |
    heading[not(parent::section or parent::contents) and not(parent::p)] |
    language-desc | country-desc | graphic[not(parent::section or parent::contents)] |
    block-quote | bulleted-list | blank-line |
    bibliography | language-name-index | language-code-index | country-index | table-of-contents" 
    use="sileth:section-id(.)"/>
```

The [DRY principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) reminds us that when we have duplication of data, we run into problems keeping the multiple copies synchronized. Indeed that just happened to me, causing a bug that took a while to track down.

So I would like to be able to share a single, common match pattern between the two keys. AFAIK you can't do that using a variable. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: It depends on what version of XSLT you are using. If 2.0, you could define a function which encapsulates the match condition.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: XSLT 2.0 (see tag). Using a function would be an option, but it seems like a slow option for building a key, as it wouldn't fit the common use cases where elements are indexed by their names. Depending on the processor. I already don't like the fact that I've used a function in `use=`. But maybe it's not a big deal. Other than that, I think a function would be a good way to encapsulate the common criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a two-level hierarchy of keys?

like so...

```
<xsl:key name="narrowable-things" match="p | p-cont |
    heading[not(parent::section or parent::contents) and not(parent::p)] |
    language-desc | country-desc | graphic[not(parent::section or parent::contents)] |
    block-quote | bulleted-list | blank-line |
    bibliography | language-name-index | language-code-index | country-index | table-of-contents" 
    use="'universe'"/>

<xsl:key name="narrow-things-by-columnset" match="key('narrowable-things','universe')" use="sileth:columnset-id(.)"/>
<xsl:key name="narrow-things-by-section"   match="key('narrowable-things','universe')" use="sileth:section-id(.)"  />
```

Comment: Interesting idea! Is it allowed? If so, I would prefer this solution, since it stays "in XSLT" rather than going down to the XML entity level.

Comment: @LarsH, yes it will work, with one caveat: The nodes being matched must be in a tree whose root is a document(). If not, it is not an error, but no match will occur.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to review what the alternatives are to the root being a `document()` to see whether that's going to matter in my case.

Comment: I'm trying to think, in the context of what document will the `key('narrowable-things', 'universe')` calls be evaluated? In the context of the source document? of the stylesheet document?

Comment: OK, the answer is, in the context of the source document (at least when I tested it in Saxon 9.4.0.4). I expect that's the required behavior for XSLT, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note to all: be **very very** sure to use quotes-within-quotes, as Sean did, for the value of the `use` attribute of the base key (`use="'universe'"`). I had `use='all'`, which looked so natural, but was of course wrong, and eluded my debugging skills for hours. There is no child element by that name! `<facepalm>`

Answer (score 4):

I'd define a general entity with the pattern, and refer to it from the two locations.  So the stylesheet would begin

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY match-elements "p | p-cont 
  | heading[not(parent::section or parent::contents) 
      and not(parent::p)] 
  | language-desc | country-desc 
  | graphic[not(parent::section or parent::contents)] 
  | block-quote | bulleted-list | blank-line 
  | bibliography | language-name-index | language-code-index
  | country-index | table-of-contents">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
...
```

And the two key uses would be:

```
<xsl:key name="narrow-things-by-columnset" 
         match="&match-elements;" 
         use="sileth:columnset-id(.)"/>

<!-- DONE: DRY: Isn't is nice to be able to share the above 
     match pattern instead of duplicating it?
     Hooray for general entities! -->

<xsl:key name="narrow-things-by-section" 
         match="&match-elements;"
         use="sileth:section-id(.)"/>
```

Comment: OK. Will this cause any problems with parsing of the stylesheet by a validating parser? My concern is that the XSLT processor would see the DOCTYPE statement and attempt to validate against an empty DTD. We're using Saxon to run our stylesheets. I guess I'll give it a try.

Comment: Fortunately, it seems nowadays to be rare for software to assume that the present of a DOCTYPE declaration (which provides declarative information about a document) is a request to to fail if the document is not valid.  I think your concern is a valid one, but I expect Saxon will prove able to cope with the situation.